# How can I fix this syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I get this error when I load my video show view:

```
SyntaxError in Videos#show

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/comments/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

compile error
/rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/comments/new.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND
...deo.comments.new]), :remote => true do |f| @output_buffer.sa...
                          ^
/rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/comments/new.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
```

It points to this form in my comments/new.html.erb file:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new]), :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :placeholder => "Post a comment." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :value => "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

which is loaded into my video show view with this line:

```
<%= render :file => 'comments/new' %>
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new], :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Basically the `:remote => true` was supposed to be a parameter of simple_form_for.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@video, @video.comments.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
```